# webcomponents.js polyfills not working: Safari & Firefox

Tags: javascript, web, web-component

I'm trying to use a custom Web Component using the `webcomponents.js` polyfills. I've been using the `<hello-world>` element from https://github.com/webcomponents/hello-world-element

## Safari and Firefox won't display anything and give me the following errors:

Safari: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'thisDoc.querySelector('template').content')`

Firefox: `TypeError: thisDoc.querySelector(...) is null`

## Where the problem is:

I modified `hello-world.html`. It now logs the result of the template querySelector:

`// Gets content from <template>
console.log('thisDoc.querySelector("template")', thisDoc.querySelector('template'));
var template = thisDoc.querySelector('template').content;`

**The console output gives me `null`.** 
That's possibly why the rest of the code cannot work. Any ideas?

## My system:

`Safari: Version 8.0 (10600.1.25.1)
Firefox: 31.0
OS: OS X Yosemite 10.10.1 (14B25)`

I also posted an issue at github at:
https://github.com/webcomponents/hello-world-element/issues/7#issuecomment-65321859

Does anybody know a solution to get the polyfills working in Safari/Firefox? Thank you!

Comment: The same issue happens on Chrome for iPad, which isn't true Chrome in the sense of Chrome on Mac/Windows/Linux/Android. The fix below works for Chrome for iPad too.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution for the issue. You can now use Web Components with the native APIs on Chrome and with the polyfills on Firefox and Safari.

Just update this line:

`var thisDoc = (thatDoc.currentScript || thatDoc._currentScript).ownerDocument;`

to

`var thisDoc = (thatDoc._currentScript || thatDoc.currentScript).ownerDocument;`

### Why does this work?

The _currentScript comes from the polyfills and allows you to get the correct ownerDocument to query the `<template>` from. If polyfills do not exist, the above code is using currentScript instead, which is available on Chrome.

I already made a Pull request on the github.